# Remove all elements from the array which are either multiple of 3 or have the digit 3 in them. For e.g. 13 and 15 will be both removed

Tags: java

code below:

```
public int[] remove(int[] arr) {
  int count = 0;

  int[] b = new int[arr.length];
  int k = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 3 == 0 || arr[i] % 10 == 3 || arr[i] / 10 == 3) {
      count++;
    }
    else {
      b[k++] = arr[i];
    }
  }

  return b;
}
```

When i try to run test case it fails.what to do ?

```
Testcase    Pass/Fail   Parameters  Actual Output   Expected Output
#1  Fail    '{24,27,30,31,34,37,40,42}'     {40,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}  {40}
```

Comment: You need to resize the `b` array to the correct size (`k`)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return

```
return Arrays.copyOf(b, k); // Instead of your return statement.
```

This will trim the array to the required length.

If you cannot import other packages, you can try,

```
int retArr[] = new int[k];
System.arraycopy(b, 0, retArr, 0, k);
return retArr;
```

If that's not possible too, you can use,

```
int retArr[] = new int[k];
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
     retArr[i] = b[i];

return retArr;
```

Comment: not working. i tried earlier any other way of doing without using any array functions..?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your output array `b` has the same length as the input array. You should return an array having just `k` elements (to avoid all the `0`s at the end of your output array).

For example :

```
return Arrays.copyOf(b,k);
```

Or, if you can't import `java.util.Arrays` :

```
int[] copy = new int[k]; 
System.arraycopy(b,0,copy,0,k); 
return copy;
```

Comment: :25: error: cannot find symbol
        return Arrays.copyOf(b,k);
               ^
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class Remove3s
1 error

Comment: @nisha Did you `import java.util.Arrays;`?

Comment: Actually its online compiler.which doesn't  access any array functions, neither i am able  to import any packages. because its not working

Comment: @nisha In that case, use `int[] copy = new int[k]; System.arraycopy(b,0,copy,0,k); return copy;`. You don't need to import `System`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check for the whole number to check for a `3` in it.

I suggest you to use an arrayList for this.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
{
 //check for divisibility
 if(arr[i] % 3 != 0)
   list.add(arr[i]);//b[k++] = arr[i];
 else
 {
    int num = arr[i];
    while(num > 0)
    {
      int digit = num % 10;
      num /= 10;
      if(digit == 3){continue;}    
    }
 list.add(arr[i]);//b[k++] = arr[i];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following solves your problem. It checks every digit of a given number for a `3`, and it returns an array that contains only the remaining numbers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {24,27,30,31,34,37,40,42};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(remove(arr)));
}

public static int[] remove(int[] arr) {
    if (arr == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int k = 0;
    int[] b = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int num = arr[i];
        boolean remove = false;
        if (num % 3 == 0) {
            remove = true;
        } else {
            while(num > 0) {
                if ((num % 10) == 3) {
                    remove = true;
                    break;
                }

                num = num / 10;
            }
        }

        if (!remove) {
            b[k++] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    return Arrays.copyOf(b, k);
}
```

Output:

```
[40]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use like this..

```
if(arr[i]%3==0|| arr[i]%10==3 ||arr[i]/10==3 || String.valueOf(arr[i]).contains("3")){
```

Comment: additional string convertion?  isn't it bad?

Comment: going with the big calculation it seems easy, but it will consume the stack memory...:(

Comment: The additional string conversion isn't really all that bad - realistically it's going to be fast enough for our purposes, and honestly isn't all that slow to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to make this specific test pass, you have to trim your array to length `k`.

You also will want to be a bit more robust with your `arr[i]%10==3 ||arr[i]/10==3` clause. What will this do for numbers like `301`? If you're guaranteed to only have 2 digit numbers, then this isn't a problem. If you don't have that guarantee, you'll want to handle arbitrarily large numbers.

```
boolean hasThree = false;
for(int digit = 1; digit < arr[i]; digit *= 10) {
    if(((arr[i] / digit) % 10) == 3) }
        hasThree = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

or simply

```
String.valueOf(arr[i]).contains("3")
```

it's the same order of complexity, is probably still blazing fast for your purposes, and much clearer about what you're trying to do, and less likely to have a bug somewhere.

While you're at it, you might want to consider cleaning your indentation up a bit.

```
public int[] remove(int[] arr) {
    int[] result = new int[arr.length];
    int numResults = 0;
    for(int i : arr) {
        if(arr % 3 == 0 || String.valueOf(arr).contains("3")) {
            result[numResults++] = i;
        }
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(result,numResults);
}
```